# Populate C with max value of B for each row of related values in A

Tags: max, excel-2010, formulas

Goal:  Using Excel 2010, how can I get each change number's (listed in column A) to show the Max Business Criticality (from column B) to display in column C via formula(s)?

Let me explain: I have a list of Change tickets (in column A) where the change number will likely be listed multiple times (due to different locations and servers).  This means each change number may be listed once or may be listed 20 times. Each occurrence of the change number is assigned a Business Criticality (again, based on different locations and servers).  This value is captured in column B.

In column C, **of the same table**, I need to return the max criticality associated with each change and have that be displayed in each row (see image for desired result - colored for ease of differentiating change numbers).

Everything I've seen involves creating a distinct list of change numbers separate from the source table.  I'd rather not do that.

How can I get each change number's MaxCrit to display in column C?

I'll try to attach the file if I can figure out how (and/or if I have rights to do so).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In C2 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and copied down to suit:

```
=MAX(IF(A:A=A2,B:B))
```

with